# How to start Gerrit in Windows 7 after Initialization

Tags: gerrit

I did the procedures as recommended by vogella to install gerrit on windows. 
I downloaded gerrit2.10.war from the releaase site
Then I created a gerrit folder in C drive
I ran the commands
 cd C:/gerrit
 java -jar gerrit.war init -d C:/gerrit

Then on pressing enter (i.e using default) for every questions I got the message:
Initialized C:\gerrit

Then to start I tried the command
java -jar gerrit.war daemon -d C:\gerrit

but it didnt show any message or performed any action.

On checking the error_log in logs in C:\gerrit it was shown like 
ERROR com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon : Unable to start daemon

If someone knows to resolve this issue please help.
Thanks

Comment: When do you receive that message? You should provide some more information (after entering what command?)

Comment: java -jar gerrit*.war init -d review_site
 This command was executed in cmd prompt. After using the default values.. that is on pressing enter for the questions asked.. At the end it was shown Automatic startup not supported on Win32

Comment: So you have intialized the site (created some folders..), but you haven't started the daemon with that. For *nix systems, the [documentation](http://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/install.html#rc_d) tells you to use the `bin/gerrit.sh start` to finally start the daemon. I'm not sure, how easy it is to port to windows. Here are [instructions for setting it up with Tomcat](http://serverfault.com/questions/383573/how-do-i-install-gerrit-under-tomcat-with-ldap/385076#385076)

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I too find in the error log that I should start the daemon. Do you have any exact idea about starting daemon in Windows